# Mobile stylesheet switching different screen widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

Can anyone recommend the best way to target different mobile screen sizes?

I have tried media types but it doesn't work properly, so wondering whether a javascript method would suit?

We basically want a client side solution that will serve different style sheets for different screensizes, depending on the connecting device.

Any advice gratefully received!

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [www.columnal.com](http://www.columnal.com/)

> A responsive CSS grid system helping desktop and mobile browsers play nicely together.

or [cssgrid.net](http://cssgrid.net/)

> The 1140 grid fits perfectly into a 1280 monitor. On smaller monitors it becomes fluid and adapts to the width of the browser.

Just to name two.